# On view page listener inside a fragment

Tags: java, android

is there a way when i'm inside a fragment to listen when the specific fragment i'm changed?
for example when i swipe to another fragment i want to show a toast that said "Fragment Swiped,Data Saved".
like an OnClose but only when the fragment lost the foucus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the ViewPager calls the [setUserVisible(boolean)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setUserVisibleHint%28boolean%29) method when the fragments are swiped. You can use that.

Comment: i dont have this method inside my Fragment.im not talking about the fragment Activity im talking about the fragment it self

Comment: yes you do. Every fragment starting on API 15 (and all form support.v4) have it, it's on the link. You can also check from inside your fragment calling getUserVisibleHint https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getUserVisibleHint()

Comment: i do have that function,but when i check if the boolean is true im trying to show a toast.but before the toast shown the app crashes

Comment: you can `@override` it on your fragment and show the toast the moment it changes from Visible to not